# text in the middle is moving a few pixels when image next to it is removed

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage where there are 3 divs floating next to each other.
Flexbox would be better to use, but for some reason I am having a few troubles with it.

Anyways this is what I get when I remove an image:

[image]

When the image is back, everything is normal again.

Anyone knows what the problem may be ?

```css
.Capital {
  margin: 0px 0 -5px 0;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: ligter;
}

.smalltext {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.smalltextpub {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 05% 00% 00% 02%;
}

.paragraphs {
  margin: 2% 00% 2% 00%;
  width: 50%;
}

.imageright {
  float: right;
  margin: 02% -10% 0% 00%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.square {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #769DBD;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="background" class="square"><span class="Capital">B</span>
      <span class="smalltextpub">Background</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    The spatial and social structures of a city such as buildings, the transport infrastructure, parks as well as the dynamic nature of human activities and its underlying processes can trigger different collective and individual human emotions as a person’s
    response to such urban contexts. However, the integration of such human urban emotions into citizen-centric spatial planning processes is a major challenge in order to contribute to a fundamentally changing understanding of spatial and regional planning.
  </div>
  <img class="imageright" src="http://giscience.zgis.at/gisce/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/300x200.png" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="results" class="square"><span class="Capital">R</span>
      <span class="smalltext">Results</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">
    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
    IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add Html also bro.

Comment: Your question is bit unclear, can you elaborate it more?

Comment: Got it, Let me post my answer :P

Comment: @Abhishek The two paragraphs aren't alligned nice to each other. The reason for that is that I removed my image that was there before. When I put the image back, like the first row, everything is alligned nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `.container` is taking height of image while image is there, but after removing it `.container` is reducing it's height to min-content, it's a very basic rule of auto height, if you want `.container` to not reduce it's height you need to set `min-height` to `container`.

```css
.Capital {
  margin: 0px 0 -5px 0;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: ligter;
}

.smalltext {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.smalltextpub {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  min-height:225px;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 05% 00% 00% 02%;
}

.paragraphs {
  margin: 2% 00% 2% 00%;
  width: 50%;
}

.imageright {
  float: right;
  margin: 02% -10% 0% 00%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.square {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #769DBD;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="background" class="square"><span class="Capital">B</span>
      <span class="smalltextpub">Background</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    The spatial and social structures of a city such as buildings, the transport infrastructure, parks as well as the dynamic nature of human activities and its underlying processes can trigger different collective and individual human emotions as a person’s
    response to such urban contexts. However, the integration of such human urban emotions into citizen-centric spatial planning processes is a major challenge in order to contribute to a fundamentally changing understanding of spatial and regional planning.
  </div>
  <!--<img class="imageright" src="http://giscience.zgis.at/gisce/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/300x200.png" />-->
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="results" class="square"><span class="Capital">R</span>
      <span class="smalltext">Results</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">
    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
    IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of `float`.

Also, wrap `img` in a container.

This might help get you started.

```css
.Capital {
  margin: 0px 0 -5px 0;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: ligter;
}

.smalltext {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.smalltextpub {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.paragraphs {
  flex: 2;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.image {
  flex: 1;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.square {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #769DBD;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="background" class="square"><span class="Capital">B</span>
      <span class="smalltextpub">Background</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    The spatial and social structures of a city such as buildings, the transport infrastructure, parks as well as the dynamic nature of human activities and its underlying processes can trigger different collective and individual human emotions as a person’s
    response to such urban contexts. However, the integration of such human urban emotions into citizen-centric spatial planning processes is a major challenge in order to contribute to a fundamentally changing understanding of spatial and regional planning.

  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="imageright" src="http://giscience.zgis.at/gisce/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/300x200.png" /></div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="results" class="square"><span class="Capital">R</span>
      <span class="smalltext">Results</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
    IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix.

`Use same structure for both (With Image or Without Image HTML)`

`Go through the code comments`

```css
.Capital {
  margin: 0px 0 -5px 0;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: ligter;
}
/* Use same style for span class*/
.smalltextpub {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 05% 00% 00% 02%;
}

.paragraphs {
  margin: 2% 00% 2% 00%;
  width: 50%;
}
/*Some changes here (I have moved class from <img> tag to <div> tag)*/
.imageright {
  float: right;
  margin: 02% -10% 0% 00%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.square {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #769DBD;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*Some changes here*/
.imageright img{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="background" class="square"><span class="Capital">B</span>
      <span class="smalltextpub">Background</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    The spatial and social structures of a city such as buildings, the transport infrastructure, parks as well as the dynamic nature of human activities and its underlying processes can trigger different collective and individual human emotions as a person’s
    response to such urban contexts. However, the integration of such human urban emotions into citizen-centric spatial planning processes is a major challenge in order to contribute to a fundamentally changing understanding of spatial and regional planning.
  </div>
  <div class="imageright"> <!-- This is newly created div -->
  <img  src="http://giscience.zgis.at/gisce/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/300x200.png" />
  </div>
</div>



<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="background" class="square"><span class="Capital">R</span>
      <span class="smalltextpub">Result</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    The spatial and social structures of a city such as buildings, the transport infrastructure, parks as well as the dynamic nature of human activities and its underlying processes can trigger different collective and individual human emotions as a person’s
    response to such urban contexts. However, the integration of such human urban emotions into citizen-centric spatial planning processes is a major challenge in order to contribute to a fundamentally changing understanding of spatial and regional planning.
  </div>
  <div class="imageright"> <!-- This is newly created div -->
  <!-- Image Removed from here-->
  </div>
```